# Saving web search results for EANs to CSV

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x, csv, web-scraping

This is my first program in Python. Following code is taken from different posts (mostly this site) and combined together so that I can automate my routine task.

It's working properly but I need opinion from experts to enhance it further.

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import csv
import os

# reading file
np.genfromtxt('EAN.txt', delimiter ='\n')
dtype=str
with open('EAN.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

new_dictionary = {}
count = 0

for line in lines:
    count += 1
    new_dictionary['sequence_{}'.format(count)] = line

# searching items

print "Running..."

for i in new_dictionary:
    myean = new_dictionary[i]
    url = "https://mysite"
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.set_handle_robots(False)
    br.open(url)
    br.select_form(id="searchForm")
    br["q"] = myean
    res = br.submit()
    content = res.read()
    with open("mechanize_results.html", "a") as f:
        f.write(content)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open("mechanize_results.html"),'html.parser')

    for div in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'small-12 columns product-title'}):
        a = div.findAll('a')[1]


    #writing file

    if a is None:

        with open('Results.csv', 'ab') as csvfile:
            spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='|',
                                    quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            spamwriter.writerow([myean, "Rejected"])
            #, title.string])

    else:
       #print myean, '|', a.text.strip()
       with open('Results.csv', 'ab') as csvfile:
            spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='|',
                                    quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            spamwriter.writerow([myean, "Approved", a.text.strip()])
            #, title.string])

        #deleting file

    os.remove("mechanize_results.html")
    a=None
    i =+ 1

print "%d items Searched" %count
new_dictionary.clear()
raw_input("Press any key to continue...")
```

Although this code is running perfectly but I was wondering that when I used pyinstaller to create exe file, size became around 400+MB. Is it because, I am importing complete package of 'mechanize', 'numpy', 'csv' and 'os'?

Comment: Don't know about mechanize, but yes, the size is mostly due to numpy.

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple things to tackle and improve, let's summarize.

#### Code Style

In general, try to follow the [PEP8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), you have multiple violations, like:

- use of spaces around operators and blank lines
- organizing imports

There are tools like [`flake8`](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/) or [`pylint`](https://www.pylint.org/) which can analyze your code statically and report existing violations, make sure to give them a try.

*Variable naming* is also a huge issue in the presented code - variables like `i` or `my_dictionary` are meaningless - make sure to give your variables meaningful names to improve readability. Remember: **code is much more often read than written**.

#### Code Organization

Currently, you are putting everything into a single program without any organization - think about logically splitting it into functions. You should also put your main execution logic into the [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to avoid the code being executed on import.

#### Making the code Pythonic

- you can use a *dictionary comprehension* with [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to define your `new_dictionary` dictionary:

  ```
  with open('EAN.txt') as f:
      new_dictionary = {
          'sequence_{}'.format(line_number): line
          for line_number, line in enumerate(f)
      }
  ```

  On the second though, you don't actually even need a dictionary here - the keys are useless in the main execution logic of the program. A list of search queries should be sufficient enough.
- you don't need `read().splitlines()` and can directly iterate over the file object lines - this will avoid having an extra list of lines created in memory and allow to get every next line in a "lazy" fashion
- use `print()` as a *function* for Python-3.x compatibility

#### Performance and Web-Scraping related Improvements

- First of all, you don't need to save the page source into a file and then reading that file to parse with `BeautifulSoup` - you can avoid that step altogether by feeding mechanize Browser's page source into `BeautifulSoup` directly.
- You should also be able to initialize the `Browser` once and re-use for all the subsequent requests.
- Also, you may improve on HTML parsing speed by using [`lxml` as an underlying parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers) for `BeautifulSoup` - this requires `lxml` to be installed though.
- I would also use a `.product-title` [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to match product titles.
- I would just collect the results and then write at the end instead of dealing with re-opening the resulting CSV file in the loop.
- Performance-wise, this is also a good use case for a [`SoupStrainer`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document) which will make `BeautifulSoup` parse only the desired parts of a document - in your case the product links

---

Here is the code with some of the improvements applied:

```
import csv

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import mechanize


URL = "https://mysite"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Running...")

    results = []
    with open('EAN.txt') as f, mechanize.Browser() as browser:
        browser.set_handle_robots(False)

        for search_query in f:
            browser.open(URL)

            browser.select_form(id="searchForm")
            browser["q"] = search_query
            response = browser.submit()

            soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml', parse_only=SoupStrainer(class_='product_title'))

            product_title = soup.select_one('.product-title')
            product_title_text = product_title.get_text(strip=True) if product_title else None
            results.append([search_query, product_title_text])

    # dump results
    with open('Results.csv', 'ab') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='|', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

        for search_query, product_title in results:
            result_label = "Approved" if product_title else "Rejected"
            writer.writerow([search_query, result_label, product_title])
```

Might not work as is, since I don't have a way to test it. There are also some assumptions there - like the presence of a only one "product title" on a search result page per form query. But, at least, I hope that will give you something to start with.

And, I am not sure you need that [`np.genfromtxt()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) since currently you don't even read the results of this function call - hence removed that part in the posted code above.